# Xcode 4.5.1 - C programming - executable not producing output file

Tags: xcode4

I'm using Xcode 4.5.1 (4G1004) on OSX 10.8.2.  I've written a simple C program that reads scores from a .txt file and stores some of them in a new .txt file.  What's happening is that if I build the program in Xcode (command-b) then go directly to the location of the executable it created and run that in a terminal, the program runs but does not output the new .txt file.  However, if instead of building (command-b) and running the program in the described way above, if I run it through Xcode by clicking the arrow in the upper left of the toolbar, the new .txt IS created afterwards.

Why does this occur?  I tried building this program using Sublime Text 2, then manually running the executable and that method works correctly by creating the output .txt file as well.

*edit - forgot to attach the code!

```
//func decs
void getScores();
void printScores(int);

int main()
{
getScores();
getchar();
return 0;
}//main


void getScores()
{
FILE* spscoresIn;
FILE* spscoresOut;
spscoresIn = fopen("scores_in.txt", "r");
spscoresOut = fopen("scores_out.txt", "w");
int score;
int count = 0;

while ((fscanf(spscoresIn, "%d", &score)) == 1) //writes only scores higher than 90 to the new file
    if (score > 90)
    {
        fprintf(spscoresOut, "%d\n", score);
        count++;
    }

printScores(count);
return;
}//getScores

void printScores(int count)
{
printf("%d scores were higher than 90:\t", count);
printf("Press Enter to exit");
    return;
}//printScores
```

Comment: Pretty hard to debug a program we can't see. But my ESP says that opening a file is failing, likely because you specified a relative path and the program doesn't have the working directory you expect it to have.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to post the code.  Sorry, will do that when I get home this evening.